# Using Q_ENUMS in non-QT classes

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm tring to use `Q_ENUMS` in a non-QT based class:

```
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QObject>

class SignalSpec: public QObject
{
    Q_ENUMS(Modulations)
public:
    enum Modulations { PSK , QAM , FSK, PAM };

    SignalSpec();

private:
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(SignalSpec)
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(SignalSpec::Modulations);
```

But I'm getting this error on compile for the line `Q_DISABLE_COPY(SignalSpec)`:

```
error: 'SignalSpec::SignalSpec(const SignalSpec&)' is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(SignalSpec)
                    ^
```

What is the problem?
How Can I use `Q_ENUMS` in a non-QT based class?

**Edit**:
I'm just creating an object from it:

```
SignalSpec *s=new SignalSpec();
s->setModulation(ui->modulationCombo->currentData().value<SignalSpec::Modulations>());
```

I also have a QVector of this class:

```
QHash<QString,QVector<SignalSpec> > signalConfig;
```

Comment: You must have more code you didn't show. That error triggers when a copy constructor is invoked. It has nothing to do with enums.

Comment: @Pemdas: Yes I know the error is not for enums I just inherited the QObject just to be able to use `Q_ENUMS` ; The error is in this file and that line (even if I don't create an Object from that class still I have the error!) but I added the section that i'm using that too; thanks

Comment: I wonder if adding the Q_OBJECT macro makes this work.

Comment: @Pemdas: I tried that too (just before the Q_ENUMS line and ran qmake )! but still same error!

Comment: I didnt see the vector. Anything that you put in there is going to use the copy constructor, which will not work with the disable_copy macro.

Comment: QVector<SignalSpec> won't work because it requires the SignalSpec to be copyable, but QObject's aren't copyable "by nature" (and more specifically, because their copy ctor is private). That's most probably where your error comes from. It must be QVector<SignalSpec*> or QVector<std::shared_ptr<SignalSpec>> etc. That's unrelated to the enum, but probably coincided if you added the QObject inheritance together with the Q_ENUMS.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: thank you very much; using pointer solved the problem; if you make an answer I will accept it;

Answer (score 5):

1. you don't need `Q_DISABLE_COPY` because copy constructors are already disabled in base class, `QObject`.
2. you can use `Q_ENUM` instead of `Q_ENUMS` in Qt 5.5 and later. It provides more functionality, but requires to be placed after enum declaration.
3. you can use `Q_GADGET` if you don't want to sublass `QObject`, but only for classes without signal, slots and `Q_INVOKABLE` methods

Comment: without Q_DISABLE_COPY I get `'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private` !

Comment: @RYN, because it is deleted. You cannot construct a vector of non-copyable class instances, but you can use vector of pointers (or smart pointers) to your `SignalSpec`. Also, you can use `Q_GADGET` and avoid subclassing `QObject` at all.